# Pandas Dataframe ; how to compare IP address in rows of csv files

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, ip, rows

I have a list of IP addresses in rows (csv format). How can I compare if first row IP is same as second row. And second rows is same with third row. and so on. The output, either True or false to be write in new column of same csv. Please help

Answer (score 0):

next time please provide us with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) while asking a question.

Nevertheless, let me try to provide you with some answer:
I assume that you read the csv with `pd.read_csv`.

I'll create a dummy example, where I create an artificial dataset containing some integers from 0 to 5 (lets assume these are your IPs).

```
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['ip'])
print(df)
```

Out:

```
   ip
0   4
1   0
2   3
3   3
4   3
```

If you want to compare a item in a row to the next one, you can do it using `shift`:

```
df['same_as_before'] = df['ip'] == df['ip'].shift(1)
print(df)
```

Out:

```
   ip  same_as_before
0   4           False
1   0           False
2   3           False
3   3            True
4   3            True
```

Comment: it really works well. Thank you so much for the help.